# Differential equation, why use x instead of f(x)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm struggling with understanding a simple ODE. Let's say $x(t) = \exp(-t)$ so $x'(t) = -\exp(-t)$. When using Euler integration to solve the equation numerically, starting from $x_0 = x(t)$, we take a step so that $x_1 = x(t+h) = x_0 + h (-x_0)$. (See for example Section 2 in [these notes](http://www.pixar.com/companyinfo/research/pbm2001/pdf/notesb.pdf).) Why shouldn't we do $x_1 = x_0 + h (-\exp(-t))$ instead?

Comment: Please state cleary what is the ODE you are solving numerically. If your teacher(?) says that $x_1=x_0+h(-x_0)$ is the first step, it looks like the ODE is $x'(t)=-x(t)$, but that's not what you wrote.

Comment: Note that (answering the question in the title) $f(x)$ ___is___ $-x$, so that's why we're using it.

Comment: Yes @JiK, the ODE is $x'(t) = -x(t)$. So $x(t)=\exp(-t)$. (And it's not my teachers's ODE. Although I wish Andrew Witkin and David Baraff were my teachers, I'm just going through their course notes from the web.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your comment to the question, your ODE is
$$
x'(t) = -x(t).
$$
In other words, it is
$$
x'(t) = f(x(t),t),
$$
where $f(x,t) = -x$.

To solve this ODE *numerically* using the Euler method, we start with given initial value $x_0 = x(0)$ and use the step
$$
x_{i+1} = x_i + hf(x_i,t) = x_i -hx_i.
$$
Here, $x_i$ is the estimate of $x(ih)$.

---

**Your question** was "Why don't we use $x_1 = x_0 + h (-\exp(-t))$ instead?"

Usually when we solve an ODE numerically, that's because **we don't know the analytical sloution!** The ODE is $x'(t)=-x(t)$, and to solve *this* equation numerically using the Euler method, we do it as described above.

If you use $x_{i+1} = x_i - he^{-t}$, you basically have already solved the ODE analytically! How else would you get anything like $"-e^{-t}"$ from the ODE?

I have to say that I think $x'(t)=-x(t) $ is probably not the best choice for an example of an ODE to be solved numerically, because it is so easy to solve analytically. Nevertheless, to understand why the numerical method is as it is, you must assume that you knew nothing about solving ODEs analytically.

Comment: I understand that you normally couldn't evaluate the analytical solution, but I was surprised to see that now that I _can_ evaluate it for this problem, it doesn't give the correct (expected) result. But I think I see now where my confusion lies. The key is that the ODE $x'(t)=-x(t)$ can be solved by a whole _family_ of functions: $x(t) = \pm e^{-t+c}$, and when using  $h(−e^{−t})$ as the update instead of $h(-x(t))$, we select a particular solution, which may not correspond to the point $(x,t)$ where we are at the moment. Would you agree with that explanation?